# Are non-integer values of bend right=<angle> allowed in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

The MWE below uses a *non-integer value* `bend right=9.5` key and results in the following messages in the log file:

> Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
>
> Missing character: There is no 5 in font nullfont!

These two messages go away if an integer value is used.

### Questions:

1. Is this a bug in `tikz` or is that the `bend right=<angle>` requires that `<angle>` be an integer?
2. If this is required to be an integer, is there a list somewhere of all the parameters (that are not counters) that must have integer values?

### Notes:

- These messages are not classified as an error nor a warning, but I'd still pefer not to execute this *unpexected* part of the `tikz` code.
- I realize that the difference may be neglible. But, when I did the initial specifications I must have seen some difference to select this number. Was a long time ago, but I suspect that I zoomed in to maximum amount (6400%) and tweaked the parameters.

### References:

- [Meaning of bend right or left in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141115/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\BendAngle{9}
\def\BendAngle{9.5}% <-- Commenting this out clears the two "Missing character" messages

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [ultra thick] (0,0) to [bend right=\BendAngle] (3,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you spotted a problem. In `tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex` one finds

```
\tikzoption{bend right}[]{%
  \def\pgf@temp{#1}%
  \ifx\pgf@temp\pgfutil@empty%
  \else%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@to@bend{#1}%
  \fi%
  % Now, negate
  \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@to@out{\tikz@to@bend}
  \c@pgf@counta=\tikz@to@bend\relax%
  \c@pgf@counta=-\c@pgf@counta\relax%
  \edef\tikz@to@out{\the\c@pgf@counta}%
  \c@pgf@counta=180\relax%
  \advance\c@pgf@counta by-\tikz@to@out\relax%
  \edef\tikz@to@in{\the\c@pgf@counta}%
  \tikz@to@switch@on%
  \tikz@to@relativetrue%
}
```

So the negation is indeed done using TeX counts, i.e. integers. This explains why  the noninteger part gets just dropped.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [ultra thick] (0,0) to [bend right=9.5] (3,0); 
    \draw [ultra thick,red,dashed] (0,0) to [bend right=9] (3,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might add an issue at [the approriate place](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues). (If you do not want to I will be happy to do that.)

Comment: +1: Amazing as usual.

Comment: Issue reported: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/837.